# For any values of $~x~$ and $~y~$ in $~e ^{x-y}~$ the result will be integer

Tags: relations, exponentiation

I am trying to to form a relation **$(x,y)$** where x and y are real number but to be in relation it should satisfy a condition that **$e^{x-y}$** should be an integer.

Could some expert please help me here in finding the values of $~x~$ and $~y~$ that satisfies the above condition.

Regards,

Rohith

Comment: When is e^x an integer? Replace x by x-y after figuring this out. I leave the rest to you.

Comment: $e^{x-y}$ is an integer if $x-y = \ln N$ where $n$ is an integer.  So $x = \ln 3+ \pi$ and $y = \pi$ then you have $e^{x-y} = e^{\ln 3 +\pi - \pi} = e^{\ln 3} = 3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If
$$ e^{x-y}=N
$$
and $N$ is a positive integer. then
$$ x-y = \ln(N) $$

So your relation can be expressed as ...
$$ y = x-\ln(N) $$